# How do I display local image in render in React alongside my references to "className"

Tags: reactjs, dom

In my render(), I want to display "pony.jpg". However, I tried using `<img src={require('pony.png')} />` but it doesn't work with the rest of my code. The entire return in my render function looks like

```
return (
  React.DOM.div( {className:"snake-game"}, [
    React.DOM.h1( {className:"snake-score"}, ["Length: ", this.state.snake.length]),
    React.DOM.div(
      {ref:"board",
      className:'snake-board' + (this.state.gameOver ? ' game-over' : ''),
      tabIndex:0,
      onBlur:this._pause,
      onFocus:this._resume,
      onKeyDown:this._handleKey,
      style:{width: numCols * cellSize, height: numRows * cellSize}},
      cells
    ),
    React.DOM.div( {className:"snake-controls"}, [
      this.state.paused ? React.DOM.button( {onClick:this._resume}, "Resume") : null,
      this.state.gameOver ? React.DOM.button( {onClick:this._reset}, "New Game") : null
    ]),
    React.DOM.div({className:"pony"},[
      <img src={require('pony.png')} />
    ])
  ])


);
```

Do I have to somehow reference my image in my css file?

I should add that at the bottom of my react.js code, I have

`React.renderComponent(SnakeGame(null, null ), document.body);`

Commenting this out makes everything else unrenderable.

Comment: What error does `<img src={require('pony.png')} />` give you? Is the `pony.png` image in the same directory as your component file? You could try `<img src={require('./pony.png')} />` if that's the case.

Comment: @Tholle Yes, I don't think that's the problem. In fact, if I replace 'pony.png' with a URL link to an image, it does the same thing. It makes everything else unrenderable.